# Uncaught ReferenceError: i2d is not defined at Drawing.js:1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and decided to try out I2Djs - SVG - Infinite rainbow going by code on a codePen to try and understand certain things better.

I have come across the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: i2d is not defined at Drawing.js:1

I do not know how to fix it some help and an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="E:\Projects\DrawingLoop\css\Drawing.css">
      <script src=E:\Projects\DrawingLoop\scripts\Drawing.js> </script>

<title>Drawing</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="Mycanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

   html,body { 
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }
  #Mycanvas {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: black;
 }
```

**Javascript**

```html
 var renderer_ = i2d.SVGLayer('#Mycanvas', {
  events: false,
  selectiveClear: false
});
    //*I have no idea what this is so lets learn with eachother*//
    var parallelChain = i2d.chain.parallelChain().loop(100)
    var circlesCount = 50
    var radius = 50

    var g = renderer_.createEl({
     el: 'group',
      attr: {
      transform:{
       translate: [renderer_.width / 2, renderer_.height / 2]
      }
     }
   })

     g.createEls((new array(circlesCount)).fill().map(function(d, i) {
       return i
    }), {
        el: 'circle',
         attr: {
            r: 5,
            cx: 0,
            cy: 0
   },
   style: {
    fil: function(d) {
      return 'hsl(' + ((d % 100) / 50) * 300 + ',70%, 50%)'
      }
    }
  })
    .exec(animateEachCircle)

    function animateEachCircle(d) {
       parallelChain.add(this.animateExe({
         duration: 1800,
         delay: (d % 50) *30,
         ease: 'easeInOutSin',
         attr: function(f){
          this.setAttr({
      cx: radius * Math.cos(f * Math.PI * 2 + Math.floor(d / 50)) + (- 
         radius + Math.floor(d / 50) * radius * 2),
      cy: radius * Math.sin(f * Math.PI * 2 + Math.PI * Math.floor(d / 50))
        })
      }
     }))
   }

   parallelChain.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed to include the **i2djs** lib in your code.
Once its included, I2d will be available as a global object. I2dJs comes with UMD support.

```js
https://i2djs.github.io/I2Djs/dist/i2d.js
```

I2d comes with lots of functional API which can be used across all different rendering contexts - SVG, Canvas and WebGL.
One among them is **Chaining mechanism - Parallel and Sequence chain**, which helps in defining the complex animation dependencies easily.

I2djs Chaining Example: https://codepen.io/nswamy14/pen/Mdwppr?&page=1
(with detailed explanation inline)

**Parallel chain** :- You can group multiple executables to execute simultaneously.

```js
let chainInstance = i2d.chain.parallelChain();
chainInstance.loop() //to set the number of times the chain needs to be executed.
chainInstance.duration() // How long you want to execute the chain. Duration will remain same across all executables.
chainInstance.ease() //To set Ease on chain Execution.
chainInstance.end() // to set callback method, which will be triggered on chain completion
```

**Sequence Chain** :- You can group multiple executables to execute in sequence order.

```js
let chainInstance = i2d.chain.sequenceChain();
chainInstance.loop() //to set the number of times the chain needs to be executed.
chainInstance.duration() // How long you want to execute the chain. Duration will be split across all the executables.
chainInstance.ease() //To set Ease on chain Execution.
chainInstance.end() // to set callback method, which will be triggered on chain completion
```

You can even have nested chains - like chain within a chain.

Do let me know if you need more info.

P.S. I will be updating the documentation soon.

Update:
Please go through - [I2Djs Medium article](https://medium.com/@narayanaswamy14/i2djs-integrated-2d-js-328549ef642)

Answer (score -1):

Add this file "i2d.js" in a script as script source at a head  and import this file 
https://i2djs.github.io/I2Djs/dist/i2d.js
or use it from this site directly

Comment: Always try to explain what your idea is